# How to get a computed result from Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm learning Spark and trying to build a simple service which should get computed results from Spark and return it to the user. There are a lot of good examples on Spark website on how to process streaming data. But I can't find any docs on how to retrieve the computed result from it.

For e.g. I have a Kafka queue and a Spark job [like](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/DirectKafkaWordCount.scala) to count words. How to show the result to the end user? Ideally, I'd like to have a restful service which serves `/words-count` HTTP endpoint. But it's not clear on how to call Spark from that service.

Any reference to the doc or code example would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you would want to use the streaming API if you want to be constantly pushing results to users as they become available.  There is a `foreachRDD` into which you can provide a function that takes an RDD and publishes its result.  That function will be called every time the stream updates its result.

```
dstream.foreachRDD(rdd => publish(rdd))
```